# VCNL4000 Proximity/Light sensor

Tags: sensors

I want to use the VCNL4000 Proximity/Light sensor s.
http://www.adafruit.com/products/466?&main_page=product_info&products_id=466

In the package i've this 6 pin connector but the VCNL has 5 pins (i now i can connect it by myself with male jumper) but  what am i missing here? [image]
I assume that it is not an "accident" that the thing has one more pin then the sensor ; )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just cut off the extra pin. Adafruit probably just had a bunch of 6 pin headers in their stock.

Comment: Many thanks, i thought i overseen something important :)